# Fluent Repository Container

Tags: c#, fluent

I have a question about designing a fluent repositories container.

Actually I would like to get data this way:

```
IEnumerable list = RepositoryContainer
    .Of<Person>()
    .Where(p => p.name == "test")
    .Of<Member>()
    .Where(m => m.role == "role1")
    .GetItems()
```

`GetItems()` will just run a function that return items on each registred repository.

Now my probleme is that `RepositoryContainer.Of<T> return IRepo<T>` so I can't make a chain with that.

I need a way to expose `Of<T>` outside but I don't know if there any best practice for that.

The really need is that I can merge same type of item in just one methods.

Comment: Show the actual code not just its usage.

Comment: What do you want `Of<T>` to return ?

Comment: And is this f#? what's with the `->`?

Comment: i have no "real" code for now,i just want to check if its possible to do that @smartcaveman : Of<T> shoudl return a repository of T, but i want to chain multiple Of<T>

Comment: So, is what you're actually looking for : `RepositoryContainer.Of<Person>().Where(p => p.name == "test").GetItems().Cast<object>().Union(RepositoryContainer.Of<Member>().Where(m => m.role == "role1").GetItems().Cast<object>())`?

Comment: Yes sort of, but with the ability to add global parameter to the Repository container like MaxItems or Some filter ...

Comment: One thing i thought was to redefine all Container Methods in the `IRepo<T>` (so the RepositoryContainer would be just an entry point to the chain)but i wonder if i could do that in a more elegant manner with extensions methods or inheritance,